# How to grant privileges to user inside a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges, procedures

I want to create several stored procedures in my MySQL database and use them to grant privileges to users ( kind of implementation of roles).
For example, I want to have admin1(), admin2(), user_type1(), user_type2() procedures, pass there user names and grant privileges.

This is the example of a function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE grant_rights
(IN user varchar(100))
BEGIN
   grant update on Table2 to user;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I call it like this :

```
mysql> call grant_rights('newuser1');
```

Before that I tried to create newuser1 with multiple ways ( with or without quotes):

```
create user 'newuser1' identified by 'root';
create user newuser1 identified by 'root';
```

or

```
create user 'newuser1'@'localhost' identified by 'root';
```

Anyway, when I grant rights like this:

```
grant update on Table2 to 'newuser1';
```

everything works fine, but when calling a procedure (like it is shown above), I always get a error:

```
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

What is the correct solution of this problem? How should I create a user, pass it to procedure and use it there?

Comment: Option one: [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Option two: [6.3.4 Using Roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html).

Comment: @wchiquito, Great, thank you! I just used an old MySQL without any roles.